# How to get the clicked object in jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Wanted to get the clicked tree object value in `javascript`

what i'm trying to achieve is when user `clicks` a `tree node` then its related `data` i want to get the original object

**here is what i have tried not getting object:**

```js
$('#jstree').jstree({
        "json_data" : {
            "data" : [
                {
                    "data" : "A node",
                    "metadata" : { id : 23 },
                    "children" : [ "Child 1", "A Child 2" ]
                },
                {
                    "attr" : { "id" : "li.node.id1" },
                    "data" : {
                        "title" : "Long format demo",
                        "attr" : { "href" : "#" }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ]
    });
    
   $("#jstree").bind(
        "select_node.jstree", function(evt, data){
            //selected node object: data.node;
            console.log('data',data.inst.get_json());
            console.log('data.node.id',data);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://old.static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
<div id="jstree">
</div>
```

**Expected Output:**

from above snippet, when i click **Child 1** or **A Child 2** i should get below `object`

```
   {
      "data" : "A node",
      "metadata" : { id : 23 },
      "children" : [ "Child 1", "A Child 2" ]
   }
```

when user clicks on **Long format demo** i should get below `object`

```
 {
       "attr" : { "id" : "li.node.id1" },
       "data" : {
                   "title" : "Long format demo",
                    "attr" : { "href" : "#" }
                }
    }
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your jstree version is old, I recommend you to update your jstree version. but, as for the 1.0v, You can use below code to get the parent node, if user clicked child one.

```js
$('#jstree').jstree({
        "json_data" : {
            "data" : [
                {
                    "data" : "A node",
                    "metadata" : { id : 23 },
                    "children" : [ "Child 1", "A Child 2" ]
                },
                {
                    "attr" : { "id" : "li.node.id1" },
                    "data" : {
                        "title" : "Long format demo",
                        "attr" : { "href" : "#" }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ]
    });

   $("#jstree").bind(
        "select_node.jstree", function(evt, data){

          if(data.inst._get_parent().length <= 0 || data.inst._get_parent()===-1){
            console.log('data',data.inst.get_json());
            console.log('data.node.id',data);
          }else{
             var parent = data.inst._get_parent();
              console.log(data.inst.get_json(parent));
          }
            //selected node object: data.node;

      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://old.static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
<div id="jstree">
</div>
```

Comment: please see this question of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503511/how-to-populate-jstree-children-with-object-of-array-and-get-it-back-on-click

Comment: @skBangalore Consider accepting this answer If this solves your problem

Comment: Thanks alot please see the above question

Comment: have you seen this question ?   please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503511/how-to-populate-jstree-children-with-object-of-array-and-get-it-back-on-click