# How to populate jstree children with object of array and get it back on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to populate children and get its content on click of each of them

**in the below code i wanted to have:**

```
[{"cid":2091,"name":"name1","text":"Child 1"},{"cid":2095,"name":"name2","text":"A Child 2"},{"cid":2098,"name":"name3","text":"A Child 3"}]
```

**instead of** `[ "Child 1", "A Child 2","A Child 3"]`

i mean to say if i click `Child 1`  i should get `{"cid":2091,"name":"name1","text":"Child 1"}`

**here is jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/2Jg3B/2102/

```js
$('#jstree').jstree({
        "json_data" : {
            "data" : [
                {
                    "data" : "A node",
                    "metadata" : { id : 23 },
                    "children" : [ "Child 1", "A Child 2","A Child 3"] // replace with [{"cid":2091,"name":"name1","text":"Child 1"},{"cid":2095,"name":"name2","text":"A Child 2"},{"cid":2098,"name":"name3","text":"A Child 3"}]
                },
                {
                    "attr" : { "id" : "li.node.id1" },
                    "data" : {
                        "title" : "Long format demo",
                        "attr" : { "href" : "#" }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ]
    });

   $("#jstree").bind(
        "select_node.jstree", function(evt, data){

          if(data.inst._get_parent().length <= 0 || data.inst._get_parent()===-1){
            console.log('data',data.inst.get_json());
            console.log('data.node.id',data);
          }else{
             var parent = data.inst._get_parent();
              console.log(data.inst.get_json(parent));
          }
            //selected node object: data.node;

      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://old.static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
<div id="jstree">
</div>
```

**Please Note:** if get the `{"cid":2091,"name":"name1","text":"Child 1"}` on click of **Child 1** and so on..    plugin version can be either new or this one

Please help me thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is the correct solution but it works. Basically what I did was to replace `"text"` with `"data"`.

```js
$('#jstree').jstree({
  "json_data": {
    "data": [
      {
        "data": "A node",
        "metadata": { id: 23 },
        "children": [
          {
            "data": "Child 1",
            "cid": 2091,
            "name": "name1",
            "metadata": { "id": 2091, "text": "Child 1" }
          },
          {
            "data": "A Child 2",
            "cid": 2095,
            "name": "name2",
            "metadata": { "id": 2095, "text": "A Child 2" }
          },
          {
            "data": "A Child 3",
            "cid": 2098,
            "name": "name3",
            "metadata": { "id": 2098, "text": "A Child 3" }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "attr": { "id": "li.node.id1" },
        "data": {
          "title": "Long format demo",
          "attr": { "href": "#" }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui"]
});

$("#jstree").bind(
  "select_node.jstree",
  function(evt, data) {

    if (data.inst._get_parent().length <= 0 || data.inst._get_parent() === -1) {
      console.log('data', data.inst.get_json());
      console.log('data.node.id', data);
    } else {
      console.log(data.inst.get_json());
    }
    //selected node object: data.node;

  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://old.static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
<div id="jstree">
</div>
```

### Update

Based on OP's comment, we just need to track which element has been clicked? In this case, I simply removed `parent` from `console.log(data.inst.get_json(parent));`

Comment: every children is coming, instead the clicked child `object` has to come . **for example**  when user clicks `Child 1`  then it should display `{"cid":2091,"name":"name1","text":"Child 1"}` .

Comment: i meant to say, that way i can keep track of which element has been clicked

Comment: @skBangalore I updated the answer. This will now only show the relevant data based on which node was clicked. Although I wasn't able to format the data exactly the way you want it as with your question.